# hashbang #! url patterns for REST on the client side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, routes, hashbang

I've a single page application with my own custom router.

```
window.onhashchange = function(event) {...
```

and I've hash bangs like following.

```
#!/products
#!/products/1

#!/brands
#!/brands/1
```

But they seem to emphasize `GET` requests, I'm listening to URL changes and is there a REST based convention clean URL's based on industry standard, perhaps used by angular, React etc. to indicate a `POST` request or `DELETE` request.

So router can dispatch a respective call accordingly.

Comment: http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs

Comment: That URL structure is deprecated: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Comment: @Quentin I've read the URL, don't exactly the solution they are proposing, can you please update in context of what I wrote as an answer? I don't have necessarily to use hash bang format, can use anything as long as I can branch and display different associated content on my SPA pertaining to uri etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hashbang urls are not meant to indicate any REST based remote calls, instead it's used to define to state of a SPA page it's currently in. State means the kind of content that's visible for the specific hash bang url.

for instance for `#!/products` display product related forms, controls and associated content and vice versa for `#!/brands`.

It's the user actions on the associated content that the developer needs to interpret and translate them into REST specific calls.